# Execute VBS from Batch on All Files in Directory

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

How can I loop the following batch code on all files in a directory:

```sh
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
  set OldFile=%cd%/%%f
  set NewFile=%cd%/2%%f
  echo. > "%NewFile%"
  start far.vbs "%NewFile%" "%OldFile%"
)
```

where the `far.vbs` is as follows:

```vb
Set OldFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set rdOldFile = OldFile.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(1), 1)
oContent = rdOldFile.ReadAll
rdOldFile.Close

Set lOldFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set lrdOldFile = OldFile.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(1), 1)
oLen = Len(lrdOldFile.ReadAll)
lrdOldFile.Close

oData = oContent
oData = Right(oContent, oLen-1)
oData = Left(oData, oLen-2)

Set NewFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fData = NewFile.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(0), 2)
fData.WriteLine (oData)
fData.Close
```

Currently no file is generating and the vbs code does not seem to execute. The directory should contain a text file with some generic string and the `far.vbs` script with remove the first and last two characters.

The Purpose of this script is to delete the portions of unnecessary characters from multiple files in a folder.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have tried to make it more clear as to what i was executing.

Comment: I think you should include the purpose of the code as well (?)

Comment: @loadingnow thank you for the feedback. I have added a statement explaining the purpose of this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable expansion in a `for` loop doesn't work the way you expect. The entire loop is read as one statement, and all `%var%` are expanded at that point. To make your code work you need to enable [delayed expansion](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060823-00/?p=29993). You may also want to use `cscript.exe` instead of [`start`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297.aspx).

```sh
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
  set "OldFile=%cd%/%%f"
  set "NewFile=%cd%/2%%f"
  echo. > "!NewFile!"
  cscript.exe //NoLogo far.vbs "!NewFile!" "!OldFile!"
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Do you have any references that would help me to understand these concepts better. Really appreciate the feedback and help!

Comment: There are two links in my answer.